# How to open youtube application in iphone5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube

I am using youtube app in my app but when I open it in iPhone5 ios7.1.1, then it does not open my youtube channel and instead it opens youtube home page.
So, how to redirect it my youtube channel. Actually this reflect youtube version.

```
   NSURL *youtubeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"youtube://user/UCdCsY57HeAs1gb575scqA"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:youtubeURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:youtubeURL];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCdCsY57ZfHeAs1gb575scqA"]];
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: in iphone 5 youtube app installed ?

Comment: I have this Actually problem is in youtube version in new version this code not work...any idea how to use this new youtube version ??